# Bitcoin-qt requesting reindex on already indexed blockchain data directory

Tags: bitcoin-core, full-node, raspberry-pi, reindex

To save time, I synced the blockchain on my laptop for import to my Raspberry Pi node. I had set txindex=1. When setting txindex=1 on my Raspberry Pi and pointing the data directory to my previously synced blockchain, launching bitcoin-qt warns me that reindex must be requested if txindex previously was set to 0.

This doesn't seem right. I've already indexed these blocks. Is there a way for me to move my synced and indexed blockchain from one machine to another without having to reindex?